# OEM Grid Control Template

Tags: oracle, oracle-grid-control

I create an monitoring template for my database on OEM GC, apply it on somes database and now i want to know what database is using this template.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle implemented monitoring templates a bit differently than you might expect.  When you apply a template to a database it doesn't associate the template with the database, but instead applies the template settings to the database.  This is why modifying the template after it has been applied to the database has no effect until it is re-applied to the database.

The [11.1 Oracle Enterprise Manager documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11857_01/em.111/e16790/monitoring.htm#EMADM9032) explains how to use the "Compare Monitor Template" feature to determine how closely the template matches a particular target.  In this way you can determine if the template has been applied to the database.

> Deciding how and when to apply a template is simplified by using the
>   Compare Monitoring Template feature. This feature allows you to see at
>   a glance how metric and policy settings defined in a template differ
>   from those defined on the destination target. Compare Monitoring
>   Template is especially useful when working with aggregate targets such
>   as groups and systems. For example, after you apply a Monitoring
>   Template to a group, you want to verify that the group members now
>   have the same monitoring settings as the template. The Compare
>   Monitoring Template feature makes checking simple. You can also
>   schedule this as a report, allowing you to check periodically if the
>   group members still follow the template settings.